# “Wirtinger differential equation”

Tags: complex-analysis

Going through the geometric quantization procedure of the harmonic oscillator, I stumbled upon the following equation

$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \bar z} = z \phi, $$

where $\phi$ is a smooth function from $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ and $ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ is the Wirtinger operator. And $ \phi=f(z)e^{|z|^{2}} $, $f$ analytic, is the solution. I could verify $\phi$ is a solution but why are these the only solutions?

Comment: just let $f=\phi e^{-|z|^2}$ and show $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$ by the chain rule - can you finish now?

Comment: Yes I can. Thank You

Comment: happy to be of help!